# If $x$ and $y$ are acute, and $\sin y = 3 \cos (x+y) \sin x$⁡, then find the maximum value of $\tan y$

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Given $x,y$ are acute angles such that
>   $$\sin y = 3 \cos(x+y)\sin x$$
>   Find the maximum value of $\tan ⁡y$.

Attempt:
We have

$$\begin{aligned} 3(\cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y) \sin x & = \sin y \\ 3 \cos x \sin x - 3 \sin^2 x \tan y & = \tan y \\ 3 \cos x \sin x & = \tan y(1 +3 \sin^2 x) \\ \tan y & = \dfrac{3 \sin x \cos x} {1+3 \sin^2 x} \end{aligned}$$

Now, how about the next step? Or maybe I did some mistakes?

Comment: I think now you could use $1 = \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x$, then divide the top and the bottom by $\cos^2 x$ and transform the equation to a fraction of $\tan x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM $$\tan{y}=\frac{3\sin{x}\cos{x}}{1+3\sin^2x}=\frac{3\sin{x}\cos{x}}{\cos^2x+4\sin^2x}\leq\frac{3\sin{x}\cos{x}}{2\sqrt{\cos^2x\cdot4\sin^2x}}=\frac{3}{4}.$$
The equality occurs for $\cos{x}=2\sin{x},$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir.

Comment: @Shane Dizzy Sukardy You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Put $t = \tan x$, then $\tan y = \dfrac{3t}{1+4t^2}\le \dfrac{3t}{4t} = \dfrac{3}{4}$, which is the max of $\tan y$ with equality occurs when $t = \dfrac{1}{2}$ or $2\sin x = \cos x$...the rest is simple...

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan y=\dfrac{3\tan x}{1+4\tan^2x}$$

$$\iff(4\tan y)\tan ^2x-3\tan x+\tan y=0$$ which is a Quadratic Equation $\tan x$

As $\tan x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

i.e., $$3^2-4(4\tan y)\ge0\tan y\iff\tan^2y\le\dfrac9{16}\iff-\dfrac34\le\tan y\le\dfrac34$$